# Firestore transaction with query issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I am trying to run a transaction which requires to get the data from a query:

```
firestore
          .runTransaction((transaction) => {
            const query = firestore
              .collection("Lottories")
              .doc("R3DYubrqFbbVfQNjYXfh")
              .collection("sets")
              .where("isAvailable", "==", false)
              .limit(1);
            return transaction.get(query).then((snapshot) => {
              const ticketDoc = snapshot.docs[0];
              const ticketDocData = ticketDoc.data();
              const lottoUpdate = firestore
                .collection("Lottories")
                .doc("R3DYubrqFbbVfQNjYXfh")
                .collection("sets")
                .doc(ticketDoc.id);
              const ticketUpdate = firestore
                .collection("UserLotto")
                .doc(userId)
                .collection("tickets")
                .doc("abc");
              const countUpdate = firestore
                .collection("UserData")
                .doc(userId);
              transaction.update(lottoUpdate, { isAvailable: true });
              transaction.update(countUpdate, {
                ticketCount: ticketCount - 2,
              });
              transaction.set(ticketUpdate, {
                ticketId: ticketDoc.id,
                lottoId: "abc",
                claimed: false,
              });

              return ticketDocData;
            });
          })
          .then((ticketDocData) => {
            console.log(
              "Transaction successfully committed!",
              ticketDocData
            );
            setPopScreen("ticketPurchased");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Transaction failed:", error);
          });
```

For my application I need to run a query in order to complete my transaction. I Get the error:

> Transaction failed: [FirebaseError: Function Transaction.get() requires its first argument to be a DocumentReference, but it was: a custom t object]

I understand transaction requires a document reference. Is there a work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nearest equivalent is to do the query with a higher limit, then in the transaction, get the doc again and check again for the required input condition....

```
// this will do the OP sets/updates, but *doesn't* assume the input
// doc meets the required condition (isAvailable==true)
// return a bool indicating success
function reserveDoc(lottoDoc) {
  return firestore.runTransaction(transaction => {
    return transaction.get(lottoDoc.ref).then(ticketDoc => {
      // important, check the original condition again here
      if (ticketDoc.data().isAvailable) {
        // OP code to set/update goes here
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    })
  })
}

// try a transaction on the first doc in the array.  return if successful
// otherwise, try recursively on the remainder of the array
// return a bool indicating success
function reserveOneOf(lottoDocs) {
  if (lottoDocs.length === 0) return false
  return reserveDoc(lottoDocs[0]).then(success => {
    // did it work?  if not, try another doc
    return success ? success : reserveOneOf(lottoDocs.slice(1))
  })
}


function originalOPFunction() {
  const query = firestore
    .collection("Lottories")
    .doc("R3DYubrqFbbVfQNjYXfh")
    .collection("sets")
    .where("isAvailable", "==", true)  // note, I assume the OP query had a typo, checking for false
    .limit(10);
  return query.get().then(snapshot => {
    return reserveOneOf(snapshot.docs)
  }).then(success => {
    // if !success here, the app must deal with NO docs currently meeting the criterion
    // the OP needed to handle this circumstance anyway (if the limit(1) query returned no docs
  })
}
```

The first param of Transaction `get` really is a document reference, not a query.  This is confusing because  `documentReference.get()` and `transaction.get(documentReference)` and `query.get()`, kind of look and sound the same, but transaction is only atomic on a single doc, not on a set from a query, even one limited to 1.

Comment: But what happens when 2 users request for the read the same document at the same time. Wouldn't it destroy the data integrity of the system?

Comment: I just looked at the *semantics* in your question.  Do you really want to query for `isAvailable == false`, then update `isAvailable: false`? Should the query be for `true`?

Answer (score 2):

`transaction.get(query)` the `query` must be a DocumentReference. So you need something like this:

```
db.collection("Lottories/R3DYubrqFbbVfQNjYXfh/sets")
    .where("isAvailable", "==", false)
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then((docs) => {
      db.runTransaction((transaction) => transaction.get(docs[0]).then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) //do something
      }));
    });
```

Comment: But what happens when 2 users request for the read the same document at the same time. Wouldn't it destroy the data integrity of the system?

Comment: I have no idea. But it looks like the transaction will fail. If so, a failed transaction returns an error and does not write anything to the database.